# Error when debugging e-commerce recommendation engine

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, predictionio

I'm following this tutorial to debug e-commerce recommendation engine
http://docs.prediction.io/resources/intellij/

After completing all setup and run debug, I got this error, any suggestion how to resolve this?
I could find this class by class finding of IDEA, error only show up when running debug.

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Uncaught error from thread [pio-server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[pio-server]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/prediction/controller/IEngineFactory$class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here was likely not including the pio-assembly-{version}.jar in your module settings. See the doc linked above.